# Python csv file lookup

Tags: python, csv

Working on a project where we have been provided three csv files (by city name). Project requires to write an interactive code where if a user specifies a city, the full pathname of the city shows up.

```
def get_city():
    '''Asks the user for a city and returns the filename for that city's bike share data.

    Args:
        none.
    Returns:
        (str) Filename for a city's bikeshare data.
    '''
    city = input('\nHello! Let\'s explore some US bikeshare data!\n'
                 'Would you like to see data for Chicago, New York, or Washington?\n')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a specific folder or list of folders where all the files are stored. Because they are named like the city and this should be the user input all you need is to combine the path with the user input and the file extension.

```
def return_path(city):
    fname = city.lower() + '.csv'
    path = os.path.join(path, fname)
    return path
```

In case you have a list of paths you can search them using a for loop. If you want to search a folder for a given name or if you want to do anything with the content of the file please specify your question.